# Datatrigger appropriately changes the initial property of TextBlock but not after the object changes

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate, datatrigger

**Issue**

When setting datatriggers for my textblock it accepts the default value without issue and changes the foreground appropriately however, when the the value changes it doesn't change colors as one would expect. I looked through a few answers and I should be able to reference the relative-source in someway but it didn't change the result.

XAML Test Code

```
            <ListBox Name="test" Width="90" Margin="20,0,20,40" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDownTest"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Name="dttBlock" Text="{Binding Time}" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDownTest">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path =Flex}" Value="normal">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

MouseDownClickEvent

```
        private void TextBlock_MouseDownTest(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeLord item = (TimeLord) (sender as TextBlock).DataContext;
        var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;

        switch (item.Flex)
        {
            case "off":
                MessageBox.Show("Normal ON");
                item.Flex = "normal";
                break;
            case "normal":
                MessageBox.Show("Flex ON");
                item.Flex = "flex";
                break;
            case "flex":
                MessageBox.Show("OFF");
                item.Flex = "off";
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Prior Implementation and Desired Result**

If the person responding doesn't mind, I would like to have a larger discussion on this. The reason I'm using data triggers is because I was having trouble implementing a button that resets all of my listboxitem foregrounds to the default color (Black).

Current XAML Code

```
            <ListBox Name="friday" Width="90" Margin="20,0,20,40" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Current C# ButtonClickEvent Code

```
        private void clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<System.Windows.Controls.ListBox> weekdays = new List<System.Windows.Controls.ListBox>
            {monday, tuesday, wednesday, jueves, friday};

        for (var i = 0; i < weekdays.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (TimeLord item in weekdays[i].Items)
            {
                item.Flex = "off";
            }
        }
    }
```

I have no problems changing the object associated with the listboxitem but I have no way of changing the foreground from the button itself. I can successfully change the foreground by creating an event for when the listboxitem is clicked by using the sender being passed into the event. If there is a way I can access the textbox from the ButtonClick event, that could be an alternative solution to the Datatrigger.

[This is a small clip](https://streamable.com/nh6p2w) showing off the old implementation and that I can currently change the value of the item.

Comment: Does `TimeLord` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: That was it! Thank you, I'll update my post to show what I changed to the class.

Answer (score 0):

In my TimeLord class I never implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged, after doing so everything worked as I expected it to with the DataTriggers.

TimeLord.cs

```
public class TimeLord : INotifyPropertyChanged {
protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, e);
}

public string flex;
public string Flex
{
    get { return flex;}
    set
    {
        flex = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public string Time
{
    get;
    set;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

}
```

XAML Code Block (It's the same one as before but just to show more than the one trigger type)

```
<DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Name="dttBlock" Text="{Binding Time}" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDownTest">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path =Flex}" Value="normal">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path =Flex}" Value="flex">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
```